# Summing everything except nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I currently have a little program that replaces all 0's in my numpy array with nan. I would simply like to know how to sum everything except nan in this array. Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], dtype=np.float64)
x[x==0] = np.nan
x
```

Comment: "adds everything in my numpy array except zero" - first, no, you're not excluding the zeros from the sum. Second, `y+2` isn't doing anything to `x` or `y`; you just throw the result away.

Comment: why dont u want to add the 0...it doesn't effect your sum in any way.

Comment: @user2357112 I actually thought that, but I am brand new to coding so I thought it served some function and got it recommended to me by someone. I am actually just trying to exclude those places in the array regardless of what number they are, so I guess I fudged that up

Comment: @JACKZHANG im actually trying to just exclude those positions in the array regardless of number, they just happen to be zero in this - I guess that throws everything off haha, woops. new at this

Comment: Hi @user2357112 I have edited this to reflect what I need, please let me know if you have any solutions for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum all the elements in the array while considering all `nan`s as zeros, do the following:

```
np.nansum(x)
```